# Why did my code cannot check if the word is a palindrom?

Tags: c++, string

The title pretty much describes my question. I cannot recall what is wrong with my code, can you help me with it?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int p(string &s, int f, int l){
    if(s[f] == s[l]){
    return(s, f +1, l-1);       
}
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    if(f-l == 1 || f == l){
        return 1;
    }

}
int main(){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int f = 0;
    int l = s.length()-1;
    if(p(s, f, l)){
        cout << "YA";
    }   
    else{
        cout << "BUKAN";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to call `p` recursively?

Comment: `return(s, f +1, l-1);` what do you expect here? It just returns `l-1`.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756)

Comment: Your third `return` in `p()` can never be executed. And if it could, there would also be a path without a `return` through that function.

Comment: SO is not a debugging service. As a specific question, rather than a question equivalent to "[it doesn't work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/133817)". State explicitly what you expect to happen and what actually happens. See [ask] and the other articles in the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1):

I choose to answer the question in the body, instead of the question in the title (in line with [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) which I also appy to "competetive programming" questions).

Some things wrong with your code:

- Your third `return` in `p()` can never be executed, because both branchs of the if-then-else structure before already contain a `return`.
- And if it could, there would also be a path without a `return` through that function.
- What jkb and 273k hint at in the comments `return(s, f +1, l-1);` is probably a doomed attempt to call `p()` recursively, returning instead a the result of the `,` operators and the `-` calculation.